# Custom and different radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I found a CSS structure which can make my radio buttons work with custom background images. But they all have the same background image. Is it possible to write a structure so that each individual radio button has it's own background image but the functionality stays the same.

I am pasting a JsFiddle example: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EwfwQ/9/)

For example I want the last radio button "Melons" to have a different background image. How can I do this?

The CSS so far:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 18px;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51558405/radio-checked.png) no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51558405/radio-unchecked.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EwfwQ/14/ ?

Comment: YES! That is the right sollution! How can I do this on any element? I don't want to use the "last child"?

Comment: You can use `:nth-child()` pseudo class if you don't mind dropping old browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite your css. put this css after your `input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before` css

```
#radio4 + label:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(your image path);
}
```

hope this will help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Working and expandable code. [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EwfwQ/26/)

The name of all `radio` buttons should be same for them to work as a group. I have added `class="class1"` to normal entries and `class="class2"` to special entry.

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <input class="class1" type="radio" id="radio" name="radios" checked />
    <label for="radio">Apples</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="class1" type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" />
    <label for="radio2">Pineapples </label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="class1" type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" />
    <label for="radio3">Pomarance</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input class="class2" type="radio" id="nekaj" name="radios" />
    <label for="nekaj">Pomarance123</label>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"][class="class1"] + label:before {
    content: '2';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51558405/radio-checked.png) no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="radio"][class="class1"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '3';
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51558405/radio-unchecked.png) no-repeat;
}

input[type="radio"][class="class2"] + label:before {
    content: '444';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/M/2/V/6/F/u/radiobutton-checked-sm-th.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="radio"][class="class2"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '444';
    display:inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/M/2/V/6/F/u/radiobutton-checked-sm-th.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you cannot do this. The `:before` definition will always be there and can't be overriden.

Comment: Just another question. Why is tjis not working now:`if(document.getElementById('radio3').checked) {
            alert("1");
        }else if(document.getElementById('radio4').checked) {
            alert("2");
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I also doing same but my problem is different browsers shows diffrent alignment, vertical alignment of radio buttons is not proper, specially google-chrome on mac never shows correct alignment