# Customizing default radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am using radiobuttons and need to make them larger as they are too small compared to text for the rest of the page. How can this be achieved in as easy and simple a manor as possible, i.e. using CSS??

Comment: @Andy Kirkpatrick - see [Custom and different radio buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14317678/690329).

Comment: Thanks @ahsteele found the css class on your link!

Comment: @AndyKirkpatrick glad to hear we could help! Welcome to Stack Overflow!